# llvm 4.0.0 Initialize an AliasSetTracker class

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to use the AliasSetTracker to collect the alias set. However, the new version makes me confused. To initialize an AliasSetTracker, I need an instance of AliasAnalysis. But the old one:

```
AliasAnalysis &AA = getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>();
AliasSetTracker tr(AA);
```

doesn't work and the errors:

```
In file included from /Users/.../LLVM/llvm/include/llvm/Pass.h:388:
/Users/.../llvm/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:223:53: error: no member 
named 'ID' in 'llvm::AAResults'
return getAnalysisID<AnalysisType>(&AnalysisType::ID);

/Users.../program/Analysis.cpp:215:25: note: in 
instantiation of function template specialization 
'llvm::Pass::getAnalysis<llvm::AAResults>' requested here
AliasAnalysis &AA = getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>();
```

Answer (score 0):

in this new version of LLVM you have to use the function getAnalysisUsage and modify the way you used the function getAnalysis :
1- Add the following function in your pass struct :
  `virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
         AU.addRequired<AAResultsWrapperPass>();
  }`
2- Modify your call to the getAnalysis function:
   `AliasAnalysis &AA = getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults();`

It will work now :)